# How to create trigger in DB with help of `DBIx::Class` using add_trigger method?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I want to add trigger into my database. I use `DBIx::Class` and follow these examples: [1](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/SQL-Translator-0.11021/lib/SQL/Translator/Schema.pm#add_trigger), [2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Adding_Indexes_And_Functions_To_Your_SQL).
My code is:

```
package App::Schema;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Schema/;
__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces();

sub sqlt_deploy_hook {
    my ($self, $schema) = @_;
    $schema->add_trigger( name => 'foo' );
}
```

1;

But I get this error:

```
Failed to translate to YAML: translate: Error with producer 'SQL::Translator::Producer::YAML': Can't call method "name" on an undefined value at /home/kes/work/projects/x/app/local/lib/perl5/SQL/Translator/Schema/Trigger.pm line 198
```

When run command with all environment variables as required by `dbic-migration`:

```
dbic-migration --force --schema_class App::Schema --database PostgreSQL -Ilib prepare
```

Which point me somewhere into [`SQL::Translator::Schema::Trigger`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Translator::Schema::Trigger)

What did I miss? How to fix this error?

**UPD**

Even when I add all arguments I got error:

```
Failed to translate to YAML: translate: Error with parser 'SQL::Translator::Parser::DBIx::Class': Table named users doesn't exist at /home/kes/work/projects/x/app/local/lib/perl5/SQL/Translator/Schema/Trigger.pm line 54
```

[Here](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/SQL-Translator-0.11021/lib/SQL/Translator/Schema/Trigger.pm#L54) the target line:

```
my $table = $args->{schema}->get_table($arg)
   or die "Table named $arg doesn't exist";
```

Modified code:

```
sub sqlt_deploy_hook {
    my ($self, $schema) = @_;

    warn "TABLES: " ,$schema->get_tables ,"\n";
    $schema->add_trigger(()
        ,name =>  'foo'
        ,perform_action_when => 'after'
        ,database_events     => 'insert'
        ,on_table => 'users'
        ,action => 'text'
        ,scope => 'row'
    );
}
```

This code produce next warnings:

```
TABLES: users
TABLES: dbix_class_deploymenthandler_versions
```

But DB has only one table at the moment. I expect it at least should produce:

```
TABLES: users dbix_class_deploymenthandler_versions
```

How to create trigger in `DB`?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe the problem with [DBIx::Class::ResultSource::default_sqlt_deploy_hook](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSource.pm#default_sqlt_deploy_hook):

> which was originally designed to expect the Result class name and the $sqlt_table instance of **the table being deployed**

As work around add next line of code before `add_trigger`:

```
return   unless grep $_ eq 'users',  $schema->get_tables;
```

But the recommend way is to create deploy/upgrade/downgrade `.sql` files manually